# Почему vertical-align: middle ниже середины?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

i {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

i.top {vertical-align: top;}
i.middle {vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div>foo<i class="top">top</i><i class="middle">middle</i>baz</div>
```

Comment: Мне тоже интересно... При этом если поставить div'у `display: table`, a `i `- `display: table-cell`, работает как нужно.

Comment: Проблема решается, если родительскому контейнеру задать `font-size:0;` (предварительно `foo` и `baz` обернув в теги и уже всем дочерним элементам задать размер шрифта). Такое решение позволяет убирать надоедливый отступ между `inline` блоками, который тем больше, чем `font-size` у элементов. На первый взгляд кажется, что убери ты `middle` и получишь тот же результат, но нет, измени `line-height` и сразу увидишь разброс высот. Теоретик я слабый, поэтому даже догадок строить не буду.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался: для `vertical-align: middle` серединой является не середина родительского блока, а середина строчной буквы `x`. Но из-за того, что чаще всего высота `x` меньше высоты прописных букв, её середина оказывается немного ниже середины блока. При этом у дочернего блока (того, который с `middle`) для выравнивания берётся середина именно блока, и положение этой середины подгоняется под середину строчной буквы `x` родительского блока, в результате чего всё и съезжает.

Все точные съезжания зависят от текущего шрифта и его размера: если поставить шрифт, в котором высота всех букв будет одинакова, то `middle` может заработать как ожидается (правда, тогда появятся другие проблемы, но это другая история).

Формальное определение из [стандарта](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#valdef-alignment-baseline-middle):

> `middle`: Align the vertical midpoint of the box with the baseline of the parent box plus half the [x-height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height) of the parent.