# В чем особенности вертикального выравнивания в safari для ios?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Нужно выровнять по вертикали симметричный символ к примеру "*" в блоке #big заданной ширины и высоты в x px:

```
<div id="big">
 <div id="small">*</div>
</div>
```

Пробовал 2 техники:

```
1) 
#big{
   line-height: x px;
   height: x px;
   ...
}   

#small{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}


2)
#big{
    display: table;
    ...
} 
#small{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    ...
}
```

В мобильном chrome и edge все ок, safari для ios - нет. Символ всегда чуть ниже центра(но это заметно).

В чем может быть причина? Какие еще техники можно использовать, но так что бы решение было кросс-браузерным?

Comment: Символ "*" лично у меня нифига не симметричен и торчит заметно выше других символов и по центру в принципе не выровнится, это во-первых

Comment: Во-вторых, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758915

Comment: andreymal, "если поставить шрифт, в котором высота всех букв будет одинакова" - какой шрифт лучше взять(который вероятно есть во всех браузерах)?

Comment: Если у вас задача запихнуть звёздочку точно по центру — просто сделайте картинку, проще будет

Comment: andreymal, в общем - да, но мне нужно прям сейчас, а картинки долго делать, есть много модификаций стилей блоков. Поменять шрифт, если такой есть - быстро.

Comment: Который есть во всех браузерах — вряд ли. Можно попробовать найти и подобрать какой-нибудь с Google Fonts

Comment: andreymal, спасибо!

Comment: andreymal, взял этот https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Syncopate?selection.family=Syncopate, но снова центрирование не работает в safari. И если это проблема в  vertical-align: middle, почему line-height не работает как нужно?

Comment: По вашей ссылке тоже хорошо видно, что звёздочка у этого шрифта несимметричная и по центру не выровнится

Comment: Подозреваю, за это время уже можно было нарисовать и поставить картинку)

Comment: Я на самом деле не со звездочкой это делаю)

Answer (score 0):

```
    #big {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: yellow;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

#small {
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

или пришли ссылку на html с css. для конкретики.